# Why doesn't Guile have /usr/local in path?

Tags: gnu, fhs

I've noticed when compiling and installing modules for Guile in `/usr/local` that they cannot be found, while setting the prefix to `/usr` they work as intended. Is there a reason why Guile doesn't have `/usr/local` set as a path?

Comment: What are the contents of `%load-path` ? Did you install guile from source or from a distribution-supplied package?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It returns the output: `(/home/gareth-anthony-hulse/.emacs.d/elpa/geiser-20181128.1152/scheme/guile/ /usr/share/guile/2.2 /usr/share/guile/site/2.2 /usr/share/guile/site /usr/share/guile)`. I am using Antergos Linux with Guile installed from the repo.